# Windows PDF Printer from a service

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a windows app that occasionally (like once a day) saves a report in PDF Format at a predefined folder location all silently.

I use Bullzip for this.

So app basically just prints to bullzip like it would a normal printer and bullzip silently handles the rest.

I am now trying to convert this app to a proper service but I am struggling to find a PDF printer service that can handle connections from a service,
Has anyone any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Win2PDF](https://www.win2pdf.com) [works from a Windows Service](https://helpdesk.win2pdf.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/230/4/using-win2pdf-from-a-windows-service) if you print silently by setting the file name using the Windows API, or by using the [PDFDefaultFileName](https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/specifyinganoutputfilename.html) registry setting.  If you use a registry setting, you must use the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Dane Prairie Systems\Win2PDF" location because the HKEY_CURRENT_USER locations are not available from a Windows service.